# Where should variables be declared?

Tags: java

I have a complicated condition inside `else` block inside a loop. So I decided to form some new variables to simplify this condition. Where should I declare these variables?

```
//here 1
for (...) {
   //here 2
   if(...) {

   } else {
      //here 3
      if (cond1 && cond2){}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare variables closest as possible to their usages, and in the "smallest" scope possible.

In your example, if cond1,cond2 are used ONLY when you write them in the sample, they should be declared in `here 3`.

Comment: Since both variable are inside a for loop, it might be more efficient to declare them outside the loop to avoid constant memory allocation.

Comment: @ortis Micro-optimization is for compilers, readability is for programmers. Trust your compiler to do that for you, and make your code more readable (and declaring them in the inner loop is much more readable). Rethink this approach only if your profiler says it's a problem, otherwise - stick to readability.

Comment: @ortis Also, if the variables are primitives - it really makes no difference anyway, they are going to be allocated on a fixed place in the stack anywya.

Comment: @amit if you declare the variables in `here3`, for each iteration there will be 2 allocations. Even if java has a great garbage collection, IMO this is not a good approach in general.

Comment: @FabrizioMorello Read above comments. This is true only for none primitives, and I am confident the compiler will optimize it for you. **Micro optimization is for compilers, readbility is for programmers**

Answer (score 2):

You should declare variables where they are needed, so in this case probably in `here 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution is this :

```
 boolean cond1,cond2 = false;
    for (...) {
       //here 2
       if(...) {

       } else {
          cond1 = ...
          cond2 = ...
          if (cond1 && cond2){}
       }
    }
```

this allows you to allocate no memory for variables at each iteration.